# Safe way to check "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" in java?

Tags: java

I have a service that processes incoming events with some date time fields.

They come in this kind of format: "2023-08-26T00:30:00Z". When the date is undefined, it comes in like this "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z". Basically it is their way of representing null.

What is a safe way for me to check for this in our app? I emphasize safe because if the condition I use does not work properly, it can cause a big problem. The reason for this is: we use this date value to determine a time interval for a sporting event. It is a heuristic that takes multiple date intervals, and merges them together.

The event comes in like this

```
"event" : {
    "game_time_windows": [
        {
            "startTime": "2023-08-26T00:30:00Z",
            "endTime": "2023-08-26T02:30:00Z"
        },
        {
            "startTime": "2023-08-26T00:40:00Z",
            "endTime": "2023-08-26T02:40:00Z"
        },
        {
            "startTime": "2023-08-26T00:50:00Z",
            "endTime": "2023-08-26T02:50:00Z"
        }
...
    ]
}
```

And then we merge them like so:

```
actual_game_start_time = min(startTime1, startTime2, ...)
actual_game_end_time = max(endTime1, endTime2, ...)
```

So if we accidentally parse the value "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z", we risk getting a final result that has a start time of the beginning of time, and this has very bad repercussions in our application.

I guess I am just hoping there is some strongly typed constant value that I can check against in java so I don't have to solve this issue myself, something like:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.time.Instant;

String dateStr = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z";
Date dt = Date.from(Instant.parse(dateStr));
if (dt.equals(Date.MIN_VALUE)) {
    // don't process this value
}
```

I thought about checking the year, even though `getYear()` in `java.util.Date` is deprecated, but it does not seem to work well...

```
String dateStr = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z";
Date dt = Date.from(Instant.parse(dateStr));
System.out.println(dt.getYear());
// output: -1899
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to check if your input is equal to this specific string, but you want to do it in a.... "safe" way? What's wrong with `mySpecialString.equals(userInput)`? Is there some specific security threat that you're worried about when comparing strings for equality?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` is the origin of the time; I believe it should be parsed successfully (barring problems with the date parser), and the resulting number of milliseconds for the parsed date should be 0. So that's something you can check: if milliseconds == 0, then you have this special date.

Comment: @RobertDodier Actually, no, a zero `Instant` in Java is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` so the timestamp `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` is some large negative number.

Comment: @JimGarrison Hrm, yes, thanks for the reminder. Wishful thinking on my part, I guess.

Comment: Did you try checking the content of the string **before** attempting to parse it? If not, what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Sorry, this is a horrible interface design. You probably can’t change it? Also I strongly recommend you don’t use the long outdated `Date`  class, it was always poorly designed. Stick to java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: The safe thing to do is proper input validation. So if the instant is within, say, 10 years from now, it’s sound. If it’s your designated null placeholder instant, also accept it. In all other cases reject the input as invalid.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a few things:

- Use java.time fully and avoid java.util.Date: The java.time package is a superior API for date and time operations, and is generally recommended over the older java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar classes.
- Check against a specific Instant: Instead of checking against a "min" value, you can specifically check against the "null" date you expect, which is "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z".

An example would be:

```
public class Main {
    private static final Instant NULL_INSTANT = Instant.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateStr = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateStr);

        if (instant.equals(NULL_INSTANT)) {
            System.out.println("This is the null date.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is a valid date.");
        }
    }
}
```

The benefit of using a constant Instant (NULL_INSTANT) is that you define your null value in just one place, making your code easier to maintain and less prone to errors. If for any reason the null representation changes in the future, you would only have to change the value of NULL_INSTANT.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

Use [`org.threeten.extra.Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class, with its “unbounded” concept.

```java
if( 
    startInput.equals( "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" ) 
) {
    return Interval.endingAt( Instant.parse( endInput ) ) ;  // Start is “unbounded”. 
}
```

```java
if ( interval.isUnboundedStart() ) { … }
```

### `org.threeten.extra.Interval`

Perhaps a more sophisticated solution would be to redesign your app to leverage the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. This library extends the *java.time* functionality built into Java.

The `Interval` class represents a span of time attached to the timeline. Objects of this class contain a pair of [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) objects, meaning the beginning and ending of the span.

```
Interval interval = 
    Interval.of(
        Instant.parse( "2023-08-26T00:30:00Z" ) ,
        Instant.parse( "2023-08-26T02:30:00Z" )
    }
;
```

The `Interval` class can generate (and parse) text in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals).

> interval.toString(): 2023-08-26T00:30:00Z/2023-08-26T02:30:00Z

#### `Duration`

You can ask the `Interval` for a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) of time elapsed. A `Duration` is a count of hours-minutes-seconds-nanos, that is, a span of time *not* attached to the timeline.

```
Duration duration = interval.toDuration() ;
```

The `Duration` class can generate (and parse) text in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

> duration.toString(): PT2H

#### “unbounded” span

Your input processor can produce an `Interval` object where either the start or the end is missing. The `Interval` class represents "missing" by using [`Instant.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#MIN) & [`Instant.MAX`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#MAX) rather than `null`. Such a value marks the `Interval` as “unbounded”.

```
// Input processor returns an `Interval` object.
final String NULL_FLAG = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" ;

if( 
    startInput.equals( NULL_FLAG ) && endInput.equals( NULL_FLAG )
) {
    return Interval.ALL ;  // An interval over the whole time-line, from Instant.MIN to Instant.MAX.
} 

if( 
    startInput.equals( NULL_FLAG ) 
) {
    return Interval.endingAt( Instant.parse( endInput ) ) ;
} 

if( 
    endInput.equals( NULL_FLAG ) 
) {
    return Interval.startingAt( Instant.parse( endInput ) ) ;
} 

return 
    Interval.of(
        Instant.parse( startInput ) ,
        Instant.parse( endInput )
    }
;
```

The calling code can then inspect the `Interval` object. That class offers methods to detect if either the start and/or end is “unbounded”, that is, holds `Instant.MIN` or `Instant.MAX` respectively.

```
if ( interval.isUnboundedStart() ) { … }
if ( interval.isUnboundedEnd() ) { … }
```

#### Other handy methods

You may find other methods on that class to be useful.

```
if ( interval.isEmpty() ) { … }  // Start and end are the same moment.
```

To get the very earliest start and the latest end, combine the intervals. Then interrogate for the resulting combo interval’s start and end.

```
Interval combo = intervalX.union( intervalY ).union( intervalZ ) ;
if ( combo.isEmpty() ) { … }                // The start equals the end.
else if ( combo.isUnboundedStart() ) { … }  // The start is `Instant.MIN`.
else if ( combo.isUnboundedEnd() ) { … }    // The end is `Instant.MAX`.
else {
    Instant earliestStart = combo.getStart() ;
    Instant latestEnd = combo.getEnd() ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### `Optional` wrapper

I like the [Answer by Benitez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981183/642706). And I like the [Comment by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76981132/safe-way-to-check-0001-01-01t000000z-in-java#comment135708930_76981132) suggesting you do proper input validation up front, before your business logic.

In combining those ideas, I think of using [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html). Process inputs first, detecting the value meant to indicate a null date-time value. The input processor returns an empty `Optional` for such null-indicative strings. Otherwise the input processor returns an `Optional` whose payload is a `Instant` object.

```
// Input processor
// Returns Optional < Instant >
if( input.equals( "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" ) ) {
    return Optional.empty() ;
} else {
    return Optional.of( Instant.parse( input ) ) ;
}
```

The use of `Optional` forces the calling methods to deal with the fact that the `Instant` they expect may not be present. Perhaps this is what you meant by “safe”.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only dealing with recent dates, I recommend comparing against the java.time.Instant.EPOCH constant.

```
        String dateStr = "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateStr);
        if(instant.isBefore(java.time.Instant.EPOCH)){
           // don't process this value
        }
        Date dt = Date.from(instant);
```

But if you want to be on the extra safe side, you could make your own java.time.Instant constant that is somewhere around 2 AD.

Comment: Setting a limit to instants you accept to process is a good idea. The 1970 epoch seems rather arbitrary to me. Better to ask business what is a good limit. Judging from the examples in the question the instants seem to be very current, so maybe anything older than a day can be considered invalid. Neither you nor I know, but the OP can find out.